# When using a foreign remote node does the transaction signing happen on my wallet or on the node?

Tags: security, remote-access

I don't understand the architecture of Monero wallet(s) - on OSX or on Android.

When I choose not to run my own full node/daemon and use (foreign) remote node instead, how does the security of signing work?

Is the wallet just the GUI to the node and all the cryptography with private keys happens elsewhere, thereby significantly threatening security OR does the signing happen on my hardware that just uses the remote node to connect to the network?

Thanks,
Michal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wallet does the signing. The node never gets access to the the keys.

The node's purpose is to keep a local copy of the blockchain in sync with the network at large, and relay transactions made by the wallet. The wallet's purpose is to find incoming transactions and make outgoing transactions using the node. By the time the node sees a transaction, it's fully created, and bitwise the exact same as it will be stored in the chain [1].

[1] Later on, some nodes may elect to prune some parts of transactions, but this is a local storage choice.